# CSS- how to re-arrange input format for forum page

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

I am working on a forum page and am trying to re-arrange the way my question looks on the website using CSS. This might be a novice question but am still quite new to web development

When I load up the page I have the questions in a column using flexbox but each answer appears below the checkbox. I am looking to see if it's possible to rearrange that so the answer appears first and then the checkbox below and the same for the next question.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#survey-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin-left: 25vw;
  margin-right: 25vw;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px yellow dashed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 1vw 15vw 0vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

label {
  margin: 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  <label for="Name" id="name-label"> Name</label>
  <input type="text" required placeholder="Enter your name" id="name">

  <label for="Email" id="email-label">Email</label>
  <input type="email" required placeholder="Enter your Email" id="email">

  <label for="Age" id="number-label">Age (optional)</label>
  <input type="number" required placeholder="Enter your Age" min="16" max="100" id="number">

  <label for="Year" id="dropdown">What year are you in?</label>
  <select name="dropdown">
    <option disabled selected value>Select Year</option>
    <option value="1st Year">1st Year</option>
    <option value="2nd Year">2nd Year</option>
    <option value="3rd Year">3rd Year</option>
    <option value="4th Year">4th year</option>
  </select>

  <label for="Hear" id="hear-about-us">Where did you hear about us?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="Friend" value="1">From a friend
  <input type="radio" name="Online" value="1">Online
  <input type="radio" name="High School" value="1">High School

  <label for="favourite" id="fav">What is you your favourite feature about our college?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Sports" value="1">Sport
  <input type="checkbox" name="activities" value="1">Activities
  <input type="checkbox" name="Sponsorships" value="1">Sponsorships
  <input type="checkbox" name="Job opportunities" value="1">Job opportunities

  <label for="Comments" id="comment">Any suggestions on how we can improve?</label>
  <textarea name="comment" id="text-area" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>

  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I tried to change to "display:block;" but it still won't allow me to change the layout of the way the question is positioned after the checkbox

Comment: Read here for checkboxes : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp . And there is example given in it of having input side by side

Comment: Can't you simply put the text before input? Like `Sport<input ...>`?